# how to continue loop after stopping point java

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java. I have been assigned an assignment to do a checking. Based on this table which I have stored inside arraylist. My arraylist are in form of 2d.

```
WEEK 1| SUN  | WD | AV | MON  | -  | -  | TUE  | WD | AV  | ...
WEEK 2| SUN  | -  | -  | MON  | WD | AV | TUE  | WD | AV  | ...
```

**WD** : WORKING DAY
**AV** : AVAILABLE

I have to check whether all the WD and AV are valid. but now I have problem with the looping.

My problem is, when iterator has found the string "WD", and the the result of condition is TRUE, my loop will stop there. I want it to continue to iterate to search for the next "WD" than contain in the same row and also to continue of the following row to do continue to do checking. all my data are in type of String.

```
           for (int t = 0; t < al.size(); t++) {

                    if (al.contains("WD")) {
                         continue;
                        if(condtion) {
                          }else if(condtion) {
                           continue;
                          }else if(condition) {
                            continue;
                          }else if(condition) {
                            continue;
                         }else {
                           System.out.println("invalid data");
                            continue;
                             }
                     }
                }
```

Can you guys help me give me idea why my code not working the way I want it to be? Sorry for my English.

Comment: Your code will not compile, and doesn't contain enough informativ to deduct what exactly is intended to happen. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @daniu as I explained in the desc, I want my iterator to continue for the next "WD" that contain inside my arraylist if the condition is true and if false, it will print the " invalid data" and continue looping again

Comment: I think you should check each element in the list intead of entire the list. If there is only one "WD" in the list, the first condition always true and the "else" never used. Check my answer.

Comment: It's not very clear what you have actually stored in your array list(s), you say it's 2D so I assume it is a list of lists? The outer contains weeks and the inner is a week of data, is this correct and what is the format of the data in the inner list?

Comment: hey @JoakimDanielson as I stated, all my data are in String data type. that table is sample of my arraylist data.

Comment: Yeah I get that they are strings but what does each element in the array list contain, is it the whole row from your table `WEEK 1| SUN  | WD | AV...` in one element or is the row split somehow?

Comment: hey @JoakimDanielson , it a split row. the week 1 is in the first row containing all days then continue with the second row repeat the same data. BTW, this problem has been solved. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check each element in the array list. Like this:

```java
if (al.get(t).contains("WD"))
```

The solution I guess.

```java
    for (int t = 0; t < al.size(); t++) {
     if (al.get(t).contains("WD")) {
      continue;
       } 
      else {
       System.out.println("invalid data");
       continue;
      }
     }
    }
```

In your solution, you checked entire the list. That mean if there is only one "WD" in the list, the first condition's always true and the "else" is never reached.

Comment: your code works well and suits with my need. Thank you Sir, have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int t = 0; t < al.size(); t++) {

                    if (al.contains("WD")) {
                         continue; // using continue keyword causes the loop to skip an iteration.
                        if(condtion) {
                          }else if(condtion) {
                           continue;
                          }else if(condition) {
                            continue;
                          }else if(condition) {
                            continue;
                         }else {
                           System.out.println("invalid data");
                            continue;
                             }
                     }
                }
```

as you have used the continue keyword the current iteration is skipped. remove continue (then the code below the if condition of checking for 'WD' will be executed when it's true)